# Do I need to improve the safety of my Cloud SQL connection?

Tags: c#, sql, cloud

I am working on a C# winform project and during several operations I save and retrieve data to and from my google cloud SQL database. 
In order to implement this, I set up the SQL instance, allowed the public 0.0.0.0/0 IP (so I can use this app from different PCs) and created a database user with a strong password. In the connection string in my c# project I connect to the IP with the created database user + Password.

Now my question is, how save is this? For my project and the enduser it is essential, that the data is as save as it can be. The only safety I have now is basically my google account Password and the database user Password. 
Would there currently be a way to bypass that and retrieve data without me noticing?

best regards
Steffen

Comment: The best way of sending is without a username and password. Use windows credentials.  The local and remote machines will transfer secure using a windows secure connection.  And the database credentials will use the user login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fine "back in the days".
Now, it is good practice to have a front-end proxy that uses APIs to serve data to the application.

If you can build and application that will run in the Cloud, next to your database, it would be best. Have that application authenticate users of the Winform Application and send them the information they need through API calls.
Without this, and having your application access directly the database you will have 2 issues:

- lower security
- high latency (and this will probably be more problematic). Database requests don't really like latency.

On top of it, you could use that server-side app to cache data and do some consistency checks.

However, for DEV purposes, direct connection is acceptable. Just don't put production data there.